# unable to deleting library from flutter plugin folders

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I've asked this question and no body give me the correct way to delete a package from flutter library, I want to delete webivew_flutter 2.0.13 or at least to downgrade this package because it asks for update in minSdkVersion, I really tried many ways but still unable to delete it even it is no in the pubspec file but still exists in the library folder, also I tried with flutter pub cache repair but not success to delete this package
please help

[image]

Comment: have you tried flutter clean?

Comment: yes I tried it also the same issue

Answer (score 1):

the problem was coming from flutter_html: ^2.1.5 if I installed it will also install webview_flutter!

Comment: so is your problem solved?

Comment: yes this was the problem